# Ruby: How to sort a string, keeping some characters in place?

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie in Ruby and I'd like to sort a string, but keeping the non alphanumerical characters in place.
Eg: `"hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016" => "ehllo, allsy! eens 01/cde/0126"`

I've tried doing:

```
word.scan(/\w+/).collect { |e| ((e.scan /\w/).sort.join)}
#=> ["ehllo", "allsy", "eens", "01", "cde", "0126"]
```

But I can't figure out how to put the non alphanumeric characters back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I can't figure out how to put the non alphanumeric characters back.

It would be easier to not remove them in the first place:

```
str = "hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016"

str.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| m.chars.sort.join }
#=> "ehllo, allsy! eens 01/cde/0126"
```

[`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) scans the string for the given pattern and passes each match string to the block,  so the block is called with `"hello"`, `"sally"`, `"seen"`, `"10"`, `"dec"` and `"2016"`. It sorts the string via:

```
m = "hello"
m.chars #=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
 .sort  #=> ["e", "h", "l", "l", "o"]
 .join  #=> "ehllo"
```

`gsub` then substitutes the block's result for the match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain briefly how it works?

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the question: "...I'd like to sort a string, but keeping the non-alphanumerical characters in place." It wasn't until I read your example more carefully did I realize that is not what you wanted. I'll leave my answer because it does answer the stated question.

**Code**

```
def sort_alphas(str)
  alphas, non_alphas = str.each_char.with_index.partition { |c,_| c =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }
  chrs, offsets = alphas.transpose
  chrs.sort.zip(offsets).concat(non_alphas).sort_by(&:last).map(&:first).join
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016"
sort_alphas(str)
  #=> "acdee, eehll! llno 10/ssy/2016"
```

**Explanation**

The steps for the example string are as follows.

```
alphas, non_alphas = str.each_char.with_index.partition { |c,_|
  c =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }
alphas
  #=> [["h", 0], ["e", 1], ["l", 2], ["l", 3], ["o", 4], ["s", 7], ["a", 8],
  #    ["l", 9], ["l", 10], ["y", 11], ["s", 14], ["e", 15], ["e", 16],
  #    ["n", 17], ["d", 22], ["e", 23], ["c", 24]]
non_alphas
  #=> [[",", 5], [" ", 6], ["!", 12], [" ", 13], [" ", 18], ["1", 19], ["0", 20],
  #    ["/", 21], ["/", 25], ["2", 26], ["0", 27], ["1", 28], ["6", 29]] 
chrs, offsets = alphas.transpose
chrs
  #=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "s", "a", "l", "l", "y", "s", "e", "e", "n",
  #    "d", "e", "c"] 
offsets
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24]
```

```
sorted_alphas = chrs.sort.zip(offsets)
  # => [["a", 0], ["c", 1], ["d", 2], ["e", 3], ["e", 4], ["e", 7], ["e", 8],
  #     ["h", 9], ["l", 10], ["l", 11], ["l", 14], ["l", 15], ["n", 16],
  #     ["o", 17], ["s", 22], ["s", 23], ["y", 24]] 
sorted_arr = sorted_alphas.concat(non_alphas)
  #=> [["a", 0], ["c", 1], ["d", 2], ["e", 3], ["e", 4], ["e", 7], ["e", 8],
  #    ["h", 9], ["l", 10], ["l", 11], ["l", 14], ["l", 15], ["n", 16], ["o", 17],
  #    ["s", 22], ["s", 23], ["y", 24], [",", 5], [" ", 6], ["!", 12], [" ", 13], 
  #    [" ", 18], ["1", 19], ["0", 20], ["/", 21], ["/", 25], ["2", 26], ["0", 27],
  #    ["1", 28], ["6", 29]] 
ordered_arr = sorted_arr.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [["a", 0], ["c", 1], ["d", 2], ["e", 3], ["e", 4], [",", 5], [" ", 6],
  #    ["e", 7], ["e", 8], ["h", 9], ["l", 10], ["l", 11], ["!", 12], [" ", 13],
  #    ["l", 14], ["l", 15], ["n", 16], ["o", 17], [" ", 18], ["1", 19], ["0", 20],
  #    ["/", 21], ["s", 22], ["s", 23], ["y", 24], ["/", 25], ["2", 26], ["0", 27],
  #    ["1", 28], ["6", 29]] 
ordered_chrs = ordered_arr.map(&:first)
  #=> ["a", "c", "d", "e", "e", ",", " ", "e", "e", "h", "l", "l", "!", " ", "l",
  #    "l", "n", "o", " ", "1", "0", "/", "s", "s", "y", "/", "2", "0", "1", "6"] 
ordered_chrs.join
  #=> "acdee, eehll! llno 10/ssy/2016"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry for not having explained myself better :(