# Python: How to sort the letters of a string keeping some characters in place?

Tags: python, string

I've already asked this question, but it was for [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911995/ruby-how-to-sort-a-string-keeping-some-characters-in-place), now it's Python's turn!
I want to sort the words of a string, keeping non-alphanumeric characters in place, for example:

```
"hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016 => ehllo, allsy! eens 01/cde/0126"
```

Based in the answer I've previously received, I've tried to do:

```
def sortThisList(listWords):
    for word in listWords:
        print(re.sub('\W+', sortStr(word), word)) #Error

def sortStr(word):
    return "".join(sorted(list(word)))
```

<strike>But this error pops up:</strike>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in sortItAll
  File ".../lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Not anymore, thank you ^^.
But it's still not sorting properly.

Comment: Where in the code does it give you this error? Which line, as in what is the code on the line?

Comment: In the print(re.sub('\W+', sortStr(word), textInaList)) line

Comment: How do you call the `sortItAll()` function? Are you passing in a single string or a list of strings? Your variable names and use of the `textInaList` variable are a little confusing. Please add a sample session of how it should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to apply the regular expression to the *whole list*, not the individual word:

```
for word in textInaList:  # textInaList presumably is a list
    print(re.sub('\W+', sortStr(word), textInaList))
#    you pass that list into re.sub(): ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Next, you want to pass in a your `sortStr` *function* if you want it to be used for each replacement, and have that function deal with a *match object*. You'll also want to replace `\w+` (word characters), *not* non-word characters:

```
def sortStr(match):
    return "".join(sorted(match.group()))

print(re.sub('\w+', sortStr, sentence))
```

When you pass in a function as the second argument to `re.sub()`, it is called for every match found in the third argument, passing in a [*match object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects); calling [`match.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) returns the matched text (so a single word in this case). The return value is then used as the replacement.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def sortStr(match):
...     return "".join(sorted(match.group()))
...
>>> sentence = "hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016"
>>> re.sub('\w+', sortStr, sentence)
'ehllo, allsy! eens 01/cde/0126'
```

Comment: This is good. If you want to keep all your functions try doing this. Change the print statement to, `print(re.sub('\W+', sortStr(word), wor))`.

Comment: @PrestonHager: sorry, what? That expression *does not work*; it replaces `\W+` patterns (**non**-word characters) in `word` with the *whole input sorted*.

Comment: MartijnPieters Your solution is pretty good, thanks! But I think @sirfz add a more begginer friendly one.

Comment: @Safirah: I included working code in my post; if sirfz's code works, mine works too. It's up to you, but the *outcome is the same for both answers*.

Comment: @Safirah: can you *at least*, tell me what "doesn't work" means here? Do you get an error or do you get wrong output? What *input* did you give the code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sorry, I didn't mean to upset you. But running your code just returns the exact same thing I've entered

Comment: @Safirah: So how did you use the output of `re.sub()`? What did you pass in? What does your `sortStr()` function look like?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help. I tried restarting my pc and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to match consecutive alphanumeric characters, sort them and replace the original words while keeping all other characters untouched. That is:

```
In [25]: s = "hello, sally! seen 10/dec/2016"

In [26]: ns = s

In [27]: for w in re.findall(r'\w+', s):
    ...:     ns = ns.replace(w, "".join(sorted(w)))
    ...:     

In [28]: ns
Out[28]: 'ehllo, allsy! eens 01/cde/0126'
```

Comment: Why the separate string.replace calls? `re.sub()` is perfectly capable of doing that for you.

Comment: True, it's just the first solution that popped up into my head to solve the problem. Gets the idea through, tho the `re.sub` solution is the nicer one.